# JSF Bean Validation with custom text parameters

Tags: bean-validation

I created a validation constraint looking like that

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = WordValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Word {

    String message() default "{com.asd.validator.Word}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    /**
     * @return size the element must be higher or equal to
     */
    int min() default 0;

    /**
     * @return size the element must be lower or equal to
     */
    int max() default Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

with some validator. After that I created a file called ValidationMessages.properties and created an entry in the face-config.xml looking like this:

```
 <application>
        <message-bundle>ValidationMessages</message-bundle>
    </application>
```

In the ValidationMessages.properties I added following entry:

```
com.asd.validator.Word=The words must have min {0} and max {1} characters.
```

In {0} and {1} I want to add the number of min and max of my validation constraint.

How to set the text parameter? There has to be a way because the standard jsf validation constraints has messages with such text parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
The words must have min {min} and max {max} characters.
```